# Show message if value is not available

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I want to ask. How to display message if the value enter in textbox is not available in MSSQL database? I want user notify either the value they enter exist or not in database. here is my current coding:

```
private void textBoxEmplNo_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (textBoxEmplNo.Text != "")
            {

                //Do something
                textBoxWorkNo.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                textBoxName.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();


                string selectSql = "select icnum, passport, deptno, section from m_employee where empno=@empno";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", textBoxEmplNo.Text);

                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (read.Read())
                        {
                            textBoxICPass.Text = (read["icnum"].ToString());
                            textBoxPassport.Text = (read["passport"].ToString());
                            textBoxDept.Text = (read["deptno"].ToString());
                            textBoxSection.Text = (read["section"].ToString());


                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }

            }

            else
            {
                textBoxWorkNo.Text = "";
                textBoxName.Text = "";
            }

            dataGridView1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a boolean variable will help you to resolve the issues. If so the modified try block will do that job:

```
bool isDataFound = false;
try
{
   con.Open();
   using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
       while (read.Read())
       {
            isDataFound = true;
            // populate the text boxes here
       }
   }
   if(!isDataFound)
   {
      // Display message here that no values found
      lblError.Text ="No Data Found";
   }
}
```

How it works: we have a boolean variable initialized as `false`, and we change them to true if while loops. Then we will check that variable to determine while is executed or not. if not means will display the message as required;

There is a read-only property `HasRows` of the `SqlDataReader` class can also be used for the same. in that case you need not to use an additional boolean variable, The `HasRows` property will be true if the reader having at least one row. so you can use that as well. following is the code for that

```
try
{
   con.Open();
   using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
       if(!read.HasRows)
       {
            // Display message here that no values found
            lblError.Text ="No Data Found";
       }
       else
       {
            while (read.Read())
            {
                 // populate the text boxes here
            }

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: @Miza: Glad to hear that. Happy to help you! You can mark it as accepted if it really helps

Answer (score 0):

try this;

if you have row read.HasRows return you true

```
                using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (read.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (read.Read())
                        {
                            textBoxICPass.Text = (read["icnum"].ToString());
                            textBoxPassport.Text = (read["passport"].ToString());
                            textBoxDept.Text = (read["deptno"].ToString());
                            textBoxSection.Text = (read["section"].ToString());


                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblError.Text = "No Data Found";
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the other answers, you can use boolean to check if the read returns value or not and then pop up a message box to alert the user that record is not found.

For example:

```
using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (read.read())
                    {
                        //display values as you did before
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       //if using winform include System.Windows.Forms and use 
                       //  something like the following,
                       var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                 MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                      //depending on the result either cancel the request of prompt 
                        // user for another try.

                         //If using wpf

                     //  Include Windows.message.messagebox and use the message 
                     //  box class in a similar fashion as above.  Check usage if 
                     //  you are not familiar with it.
                    }
                }
            }
```